How does each application replica read a unique message from the message broker
In RabbitMQ streams or Kafka, messages are not deleted after being consumed. If you have a consumer application replicated across multiple Kubernetes pods, how can you ensure that each pod picks up a different message? For instance, if you store the offset in a database, all pods will connect to the same database, sharing the same data. This means they will all see the same next message. What strategies can be employed to prevent this?

Each platform provides ways of doing this eg: "Kafka consumers within the same group can process messages in parallel" are you asking how those ways work? This doesn't seem like a hard problem to solve as the server will know what messages it has sent. Can you explain what part you are struggling with?

Thanks for replying.

I'll provide an example to help clarify my query. Imagine you have a Kubernetes deployment with 5 replicas. These 5 pods connect to a single RabbitMQ stream and pull messages one by one, each at their own pace. If the offset is saved to an external database where the application both saves and reads from, how does pod X know which messages pods Z, Y, etc. have already processed? Or, if you can point me to a documentation explain something similar to my query it would be great.

This is core functionality of all messages queues - as such it will be well documented how do this in the docs of whichever MQ you select (different MQ's may have slightly different approaches).

yeah, I haven't used rabbitMQ streams, but the manual says they can be used in the same way as queues, and you can def do this in kafka, you just use the same consumer id. If your question is just about how to configure software X to do this then its prob off topic

RabbitMQ streams were deliberately designed so that each consumer gets a copy, not unique message. So why do you want to use a tool for thing it was deliberately designed to not support? And why don't you use a tool (RabbitMQ queues) that were designed to support this out of the box?

It is not about any specific configuration. I am just curious how multiple consumers running in parallel, feeding from the same stream, know which one is the next available message ready for consumption so they don't process the same messages.  Doing it with queues is clear but I was thinking on using streams since according to the documentation I read they perform better. Queues it is then. Thank you for your support

I think you can do it with streams, the server keeps track of the offset and the client acknowledges receipt, same as with a queue with qos

cant find an explicit manual page for how to do it though.

The "exactly once" is very difficult to achieve. Here a post written my Neha Narkhede, former CTO and co-founder at confluence, that explains how they made it work when the feature was introduced in Kafka: https://www.confluent.io/blog/exactly-once-semantics-are-possible-heres-how-apache-kafka-does-it/

Kafka is adding support for queues now: https://www.confluent.io/blog/queues-on-kafka/
